# Check when was the computer ON?

Tags: server, shutdown, uptime

My server has rebooted a few times in the past week due to electricity cuts. I would like to know when was the server running.

Uptime only gives me information about the last time it's been on.

Last only gives me information about user login but nobody has logged into the server during this time.

Is there a way to check this with the packages installed by default in Ubuntu server 12.04?

Comment: Try `last reboot`

Comment: @muru Thanks, BOOTLOGD_ENABLE was set to No and that made me think that `last reboot` only applies to the very last one.

Comment: You should get a UPS